# How to watch a property of an html tag in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to watch a property of one of my inner html elements (li tag) inside a directive. I have tried it, but not able to get that. My html is as given below:

```
<div id="notificationsTile">
    <div class="blue">
       <div class="step">
            <ul ng-repeat="item in Model.DisplayNotifications">
                <li itemPriority = {{item.Priority}}>
                    <h3>{{ item.EndDate | date: 'dd MMMM' }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ item.NotificationName }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to watch the itemPriority. The watch is as given below:

```
scope.$watch("itemPriority", function(newVal, oldVal){
                debugger;
            });
```

My directive is as given below:

```
notificationsTileModule.directive('spNotificationsTile', function (spNotificationsService, spSessionStorageService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
    scope: {
            priority: '=itemPriority'   
        },
        templateUrl: '/_catalogs/masterpage/SPDP.Portal/Views/NotificationTile/NotificationTile.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var model = scope.Model = {
                DisplayNotifications: []        

            };

            //model.Priority = scope.itemPriority;

            scope.$watch('priority', function(newVal, oldVal){
                debugger;
            });
}
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use interpolation to set the value of the item-priority attribute:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in Model.DisplayNotifications">
    <li item-priority="item.priority">{{item.priority}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that I wrote the directive's name using lower case, [dash-delimited format](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  Angular will convert this to `itemPriority` in the directive link function.  From there, you can watch the attribute value like this:

```
app.directive('itemPriority', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    scope: {
      priority: '=itemPriority'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch('priority', function() {
        console.log(scope.priority);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ty1bJoxqd8ZBIV7CqUEI?p=preview

**Update**
You are not adding your directive anywhere in the html (there are no `sp-notifications-tile` elements).  But you would have trouble even if you did include the element, because it is replacing its content, and you would lose the list items generated by `ng-repeat`.

If all you need is to add a class to list items by priority, use `ng-class` as follows:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in Model.DisplayNotifications">
  <li>
    <div ng-class="{'alert-danger': item.priority < 2, 
        'alert-warning': item.priority >= 2 && item.priority < 4, 
        'alert-info': item.priority >= 4}">
      {{item.priority}}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is an updated demo using `ng-class`: http://plnkr.co/oR6eBPOsdHqqGiF0U7Zs

Comment: I'm getting attrs as undefined!

Comment: it must match the link function signature, which is usually: `(scope, element, attrs)` but usage varies widely.

Comment: I'm also using the same. The watch hits only once when we load the page and its value is undefined. After that initial hit, watch is not getting executed!

Comment: Why not just 'priority' for watchExpression ?

Comment: Ha!  That works too, thanks @ExpertSystem.  I am up way too late.

Comment: Hm... the no1 guy in AngularJS answerers in the last 30 days can't watch a scope property properly. How alarming :P

Comment: I have updated the question with my directive. Please have a look. Still I'm not getting that. (I'm new to angular. Thanks a lot for your help.)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to change the background color based on priority. FYI..

Comment: See ngclass.  Custom directive not needed

Comment: Is it possible to add the class to the outer most div ? For eg, in this case: <div id="notificationsTile"> or <div class="blue"> ? I may need to apply that class to that whole div.

Comment: but there can by multiple notifications in the list.  do you want to apply multiple classes to the parent?  one for each list item?  i don't think that makes sense.

Comment: I will show only one notification at a time. Based on the priority of that notification, I need to change the background color of the entire tile. How can I do that? I need to get that priority to set the parent div's class, rt ?

Comment: Is it possible to call a function with priority as argument, so that I can change the background color in directive ?

Answer (score 1):

Your directive can access the same array of items that `ng-repeat` uses to make the list.

```
<div sp-notifications-tile items="Model.DisplayNotifications" class="alert">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in Model.DisplayNotifications">
...
```

Then, you can watch those items, and modify classes accordingly via the `element` parameter of the link function.  You indicated that you will base the class on just one of the item's priority.  In this example, I am simply taking the first item.

```
app.directive('spNotificationsTile', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch('items', function() {
        var firstItem = element.find('li')[0];
        var firstPriority = angular.element(firstItem).scope().item.priority;

        if (firstPriority > 3)
          element.addClass('alert-warning');
        else
          element.removeClass('alert-warning');
      }, true);
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/zrPEFSNXGDENB6MEQo8i.  You can try changing the first priority value to see changes to the class applied to the notification tile.

Comment: Is it possible to set the class using ng-class for that outer div? For that, we need to get the priority outside this directive. Is it possible to get that to the outer div ? OR do we need to watch ? Is it possible to watch a model object in directive from its parent ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.itemPriority = item.Priority ;


scope.$watch('itemPriority ', function( status )
  {
   console.log(status);
 });
```

Comment: Where should I set this $scope.itemPriority = item.Priority ; ? I'm setting it as property in the ng-repeat now.

Comment: try in your controller

Comment: I'm not using a controller for this. This is done in a directive. I cannot get a single value of an item here, rt ? Using the ng-repeat, we are getting each items, where I need to set it to a property and watch it.. How is it possible ?